# UIWebView calling JS with arguments won't work

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with a HTML page inside. Now I want to call a JS function inside the HTML and pass some values from Objective-C variables in it.

```
-  (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView{
    NSString *selectedValue = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"initWithDataFromObjC(%@)", @"hello"]];

    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad %@", @"YES");
}
```

The JS function in the HTML file:

```
  function initWithDataFromObjC(param1) {
           alert(param1);        
  }
```

When I run the App in the simulator sometimes it loads my HTML correct, sometimes it stuck and don't finished loading. But nevertheless it don't show a popup with "hello"!

If I change the coding to the following:

```
-  (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView{
    NSString *selectedValue = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"initWithDataFromObjC()"];

    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad %@", @"YES");
}
```

The JS function without any parameters

```
function initWithDataFromObjC() {
      alert("hello");        
}
```

The second construct will run without any issues. But I'm wondering why I don't work properly when I try to pass in some parameters?

BR & THX,

mybecks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
 NSString *selectedValue = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"initWithDataFromObjC('%@')", @"hello"]];
```

or

```
 NSString *selectedValue = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"initWithDataFromObjC(\"%@\")", @"hello"]];
```

Comment: thank you @JonathanNaguin. this works +1. But when I want to pass 2 parameters to the JS function, it won't work. Is only 1 parameter supported by the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method?

Comment: I think that with two parameters should be something like @"initWithDataFromObjC('%@', '%@')"

Comment: sure! but I recognized that there was a stupid mistake, now with 2 params and more it works ;)